# How to show data from firebase in html table

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to `firebase`, I have created android app that stores data to firebase, and now I am developing web app that will show that data in html table, but I don't really know how.
This is my html code:

```
<center>
<table style="width:80%">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Registracija vozila:</th>
    <th>Status vozila:</th> 

  <tr> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>

<script>
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref().once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + val.registracija + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.status + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried using to connect to the database? If not, we don't have a whole lot to go on in order to help you. Try working through the firebase documentation and getting as far as you can that way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. To learn how to use Firebase to populate a web page, I recommend starting with the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) or the [Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) for web developers.

Comment: @CalebAnthony i updated the my code

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have an element with id `ex-table`, so this won't work: `$('#ex-table')`. You may be looking for `$('table').append(content);`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i changed the name of element, but still no data is showing

Comment: Next step is that you might not have permission to read the data. That would show as a message in your JavaScript console, but you can also [follow these steps to handle permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/23610/detecting-errors-when-reading-data-in-javascript#t=201707251307444078304).

Comment: There are simply a lot of things that might be going wrong and Stack Overflow is a quite inefficient debugging mechanism. Can you reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    if(isFirst){
        createHeaders(child.val());
        isFirst = false; //So it only will run once.
    }

    showItems(child.val(), child.key);
});
```

What you could do is create a simple isFirst boolean, and as the forEach is run in order (I assume your column-headers are the first thing to be returned.) then all you would need is something like this: